# Copy data from CSV and PDF into HDF5 using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5

How to transfer files from specific folders to hdf5 file type using python? files type is PDF and CSV.
For example i have this path `/root/Desktop/mal/ex1/` that contain many CSV files and PDF files
all of them i wont to make 1 single hdf5 file contain all this CSV and PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the below code based on your requirement details:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import glob

yourpath = '/root/Desktop/mal/ex1'
all_files = glob.glob(yourpath + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

hf = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=frame)
hf.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but its to hard to do this for each csv file in the same bath i have more than 100 csv file how i can take all of them in the same hdf5 file ??

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your comment. Now, it can take into account entire csv files in the given path.

Comment: sorry for that but I am still facing this error                                                                    File "5.py", line 15, in <module>
    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 281, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 329, in __init__
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate